# how to use images in the asp:gridview using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How to use images in grid view using asp.net?

Actually i want use images in the place  of text for example in the place of **Edit** and **Delete** i want use some images related to text. Is that possible to use images please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please define your template like this way

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="40">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server"  
        ImageUrl="~/Imags/delete.png" OnClick="ButtonDelete_Click" ToolTip="Delete"
        CommandArgument='<%#Bind("UserId")%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void ButtonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ImageButton button = sender as ImageButton;
DeleteUserById(Convert.ToInt32(button.CommandArgument));
}
```